# Use a different React version with clojurescript react libraries (reagent,om,rum,quiescent)

Tags: clojurescript, om, reagent

How can I use a different React version with Reagent, Om, Rum, Quiescent or Brutha?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Self answer since this is asked frequently:

First you have to tell Leiningen to exclude the `cljsjs/react` dependencies:

```
[rum "0.6.0" :exclusions [[cljsjs/react] [cljsjs/react-dom]]]
```

If you have other dependencies pulling in `cljsjs/react` you can use a global exclusion:

```
:exclusions [[cljsjs/react] [cljsjs/react-dom]]
```

Next you have to satisfy the compiler since it won't find the namespaces `cljsjs.react` and `cljsjs.react.dom`. For this create two files that hold these namespaces in your source directory. For instance

```
- src/cljsjs/react.cljs
- src/cljsjs/react/dom.cljs
```

Both only need the namespace declaration and can otherwise be empty `(ns cljsjs.react)`.

Now you can include any React version you'd like manually in your HTML file with a normal `<script>` tag.

## Alternative:

You can also use [foreign-libs compiler option](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Compiler-Options#foreign-libs).